# Ограничение на минимальное количество исправляемых символов

Tags: обсуждение, правки

Живой пример: в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/429706/12143) посте вместо

```
    i = is.read();
```

ошибочно написано

```
    i = baos.read();
```

Но попытка исправить пост не принимается, т. к. корректируется меньше 6 символов.

То есть сайт будет запрещать короткие правки типа исправления имени переменной `i` на `j`, хотя подобные односимвольные описки весьма часты.

В чём глубокий смысл этого ограничения?
И не нужно ли его убрать?

Answer (score 7):

Это сообщение всего лишь означает, что вы не заработали достаточно репутации, чтобы редактировать что угодно и как угодно. Исправления сообщений от пользователей рангом ниже необходимого проходят через ревью, то есть заставляют потеть **минимум три пользователя** (два на бете). И это в случае, если исправление всеми принимается; если возникают разногласия, то пользователей требуется ещё больше — **до пяти** (до трёх на бете).

Так как требуется такая толпа активных пользователей для того, чтобы исправить два символа, то это видится жутко неэффективным. Время активных пользователей лучше тратить на качественные ответы, а не на бесполезные исправления.

А бесполезные исправления, если снять ограничение, обязательно будут. Так как за принятое исправление даётся 2 очка, то будет достаточно желающих исправлять точки. Чтобы отклонить такое исправление как бесполезное, тоже требуется **минимум три пользователя** (два на бете). Опять жутко неэффективный расход времени.

Что делать, если нужное исправление действительно очень короткое, например, в коде, как в вашем случае? У вас несколько способов.

## Правильный способ

Убедитесь, что вы исправили абсолютно **все недочёты**. Редко бывает, что ошибка одна-одинёшенька. Поправьте форматирование, исправьте грамматику, убедитесь в правильности меток — что угодно.

Исправление всех недочётов особенно важно, если у вас нет привилегии править все сообщения без проверки. Не забывайте, сколько людей вы заставляете проверять исправление. Если каждый будет приходить и исправлять по одной опечатке в полностью неграмотном сообщении, то очередь проверок банально захлебнётся.

## Простой способ

Оставьте комментарий с исправлением. Или автор, или любой пользователь с привилегией заглянет и исправит.

## Неправильный способ

Если уж совсем припёрло исправить опечатку, а исправлять больше нечего, то замените пару слов на синонимы, и дело с концом.

Учтите, что подобное поведение не приветствуется, правка может быть отклонена как незначительная, а модератор может обратить на вас внимание.

---

P. S. С исправлением **опечаток в вопросах**, особенно в коде, нужно быть осторожнее. Не исключено, что вы случайно исправите код на правильный, и вопрос про опечатку потеряет всякий смысл.

Comment: И вы тоже не понимаете, что важность исправления не может быть измерена количеством символов?  Что считать все 5-символьные исправления недостойными внимания абсолютно неправильно?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: Насколько я понимаю, вопрос не в том, что «мелкие» исправления неважны. Вопрос в том, что на них будет фармиться репутация недобросовестными участниками. Примите как необходимое зло, что система вам пока не доверяет. Заработаете больше очков — будет доверять.

Comment: @VladD - как же им удастся получить эту репутацию, если их исправления не будут заапрувлены?  Вы не поняли мой вопрос.  Речь не о доверии, а о принципиальном признании мелких исправлений как потенциально бесполезных.  Вы тем не менее готовы рассматривать бредовые исправления, которые достаточно длинны?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: Насколько я понимаю, логика такая. Изменения не принимаются без апрува, потому что иначе на них фармилась бы репутация. Но неопытные юзеры этого не знают, и всё равно продуцируют кучу мелких правок, которая теперь ещё и захламляет очередь. Необходимость делать большое изменение демотивирует недоброкачественных охотников за репутацией, так что в целом это получается более-менее эффективно (а просто исправить запятую можно не напрягаясь). В качестве побочного эффекта это демотивирует и хороших участников, понятно. Но лучшего решения пока никто не предложил.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Прочитайте мой ответ ещё раз, там детально разобрана ваша ситуация. Если не поможет, читайте ещё и ещё. Вы на сайте не один, учитывайте существование других пользователей. На подавляющем большинстве сайтов редактирования вообще нет, радуйтесь тому, что дают.

Comment: Почему потеть должны пять пользователей? насколько я знаю, для ревью правок всегда хватало всего двух аппрувов (или двух реджектов)

Comment: @VladD - получается, что настоящий корень зла в том, что за исправления дают репутацию?  тогда возможными решениями будут "не давать за это репутацию вообще" или "отбирать репутацию за изменения, получившие реджект".

Comment: @Discord вы называете все короткие исправления бесполезными, не потрудившись объяснить почему. на самом деле такое деление неверно, о чём свидетельствуют многочисленные аналогичные вопросы на англоязычном SO. то есть, ваш ответ не отвечает на мой вопрос.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Пользователей, исправляющих одну точку, будет достаточно и без бонусной репы. Бонус лишь влияет на количество. / Привилегия пользоваться тревогами у вас уже есть. Пользуйтесь на здоровье, успехов. / И вы не последовали совету. Прочитайте 4-й сверху абзац (он же последний во вводной части). Если вы не видите взаимосвязи этого абзаца (а также всего последующего текста) с проблемой полезных коротких исправлений, то это ваши личные трудности.

Comment: @PashaPash Исправил числа, рассмотрел все варианты развития событий. 3-5 юзеров на большом СО, 2-3 на бете.

Answer (score 2):

Процитирую ответ с [meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287206/1532460):

> Suggested edits require a review. To waste reviewers time over a two
>   character change is not productive.
>
> If the typo really is the only thing wrong with a post, surely it
>   isn't all that important. In the rare cases where it is and there is
>   really nothing else you can edit, leave it to users with 2k+
>   reputation; they can edit without that restriction.

Скажу честно, я не помню, снято ли это ограничение для пользователей с 2k+ репутацией. Но автором этого ответа явяется один из модераторов, так что, полагаю, им лучше знать.

Ответ с [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149772/216460):

> > Comment on the post and hope that a) visitors read the comments or b)
> >     the OP gets notified and updates their post?
>
> Yes, this is the best way to go at it. Visitors will note a link in
>   the comment, and as an active user there is a high chance that he
>   updates his post.

На мой взгляд, это правильная политика. Если автор посчитает нужным - он обновит пост. Если нет - пользователи увидят комментарий. Если кто-то с правом минорного редактирования увидит комментарий - он обновит пост.

Comment: если автору не понравится редактирование - он откатит версию назад одним кликом, тут проблем нет.  сайт должен способствовать коллективному улучшению вопросов и ответов, а не ставить странные преграды.  почему важность внесённых изменений измеряется количеством символов?  это такой же бред, как измерение сложности программ строками.

Comment: Ответ в стиле "на англоязычном SO люди мучаются, поэтому и у нас пусть тоже мучаются" не совсем отвечает на мой вопрос.  мы же можем сделать лучше.  почему бы и не убрать это ограничение?

Comment: Я не уверен, что это настраиваемо для каждого сайта SE, мне кажется, что это часть движка. Предлагаю подождать ответа от администрации.

Comment: А вдруг там вместо `hello world` написано `rm -Rf /`? ))