# Что делать, если для правки требуется лишь отформатировать код?

Tags: обсуждение

Иногда встречаются сообщения, в которых единственный недостаток - неотформатированный код. Таким образом, если исправить только форматирование кода, то длина правки оказывается меньше 6 символов.

Хорошо, если в вопросе имеются орфографические и пунктуационные ошибки - можно исправить их и дотянуть до требуемого количества. А если с грамотностью всё в порядке?

Comment: Набрать побольше репутации - и форматировать все что угодно!

Comment: А еще можно стать модератором.

Comment: Не трогать чужой код...

Comment: @Qwertiy никто чужой код и не трогает. Просто иногда его пишут "кирпичом", не используя функцию выделения блока кода.

Comment: @Byulent, если код не выделен блоком кода и содержит хотя бы 2 строки, то изменение - это 8 пробелов, что больше 6 символов для минимальной правки. А если там единственная строка кода, которую не выделили отступом - ну эм.. насколько часто такое бывает?

Comment: можете привести пример вопроса, где форматирование кода к правке меньше 6 символов ведёт?

Comment: @jfs, например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/711047/178509

Comment: @jfs или вот - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/718037/revisions, для достижения 6 символов мне пришлось поставить 2 запятые (и двоеточие вроде я с этой же целью убрал, но не помню)

Comment: @Byulent в обоих примерах форматирование кода больше 6 символов изменяет. Как это к примеру [правка insolor показывает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/718037/4)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ограничение на минимальное количество исправляемых символов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/508/%d0%9e%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2)

Answer (score 9):

Отформатировать код — в большинстве случаев правка больше шести символов (иногда намного больше), поэтому очень странно, что вы столкнулись с этим ограничением. Я так вносил сотни правок, в основном связанные с форматированием на enSO, до получения 2k и никаких проблем с одобрением таких правок не имел.

Обычно ограничение в 6 символов "портит" исправления небольшого кол-ва (одной-двух-трёх) орфографических и/или пуктуационных ошибок и/или опечаток, но уж точно не форматирование кода. Даже не вспомню, чтобы это ограничение мне (или кому-то) мешать просто отформатировать код.

Но если правку очень сильно хочется внести можете оставить HTML-комментарий с каким-то понятным сообщением, чтобы было ясно, что это для обхода 6-символьного ограничения в надежде, что проверяющий поймёт, что этот комментарий не нужен, но правка полезна. К примеру `<!-- Комментарий для обхода ограничения в 6 символов -->`. Но даже если вдруг проверяющий не удалит комментарий, всё равно его никто не увидит кроме тех, кто будет пытаться править конкретный пост. Я не знаю как сообщество относится к такого рода "приёмам", но я несколько раз вносил такие правки и они одобрялись (с удалением этого комментария) и также одобрял такие правки (тоже с удалением этого "обходного" комментария).

Comment: пробельные символы не учитываются, так что форматирование - это 0 символов

Comment: @PashaPash Не согласен. А почему тогда такие правки были возможны? [1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14761848), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14498597), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14928545) и т.д. И в них чисто форматирование кода, ничего больше.

Comment: магия. я сам когда-то  напарывался на то, что пробелы не считались за символы. может быть правила поменялись.

Comment: @PashaPash Просто у меня никогда не было проблем с тем, чтобы форматировать код (ограничения в 6 символов). Исправить опечатку, орфографию, пунктуацию — да.

Comment: @PashaPash пробелы _в коде_ учитываются, в остальном тексте - нет.