# Почему исправление опечаток в чужих вопросах ограничено не менее шестью символами?

Tags: поддержка, правки

Обнаружил опечатку в чужом вопросе вот тут: [java Iterator для многомерного массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/867881/java-iterator-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0) - слово "Ввод" написано там как "Вод". Я попытался отредактировать этот вопрос, чтобы исправить данную опечатку, но получил сообщение об ошибке: "*Минимальная длина правки 6 символов; исправить ещё что-нибудь в сообщении?*" Почему я просто не могу добавить одну пропущенную букву? В чём смысл данного ограничения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Похожие обсуждения:

[How to overcome "Edits must be at least 6 characters"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81520/260198)
[How to edit answers to fix syntax errors when "Edits must be at least 6 characters"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215648/260198)
[Why should an edit be of at least 6 characters?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179873/260198)

Да и у нас тоже:
[Что делать, если для правки требуется лишь отформатировать код?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5904/15479)

Идея была в том, что правки, затрагивающие менее 6 символов, считаются несущественными. Плюс, это разгружает очередь проверок. Ну и, многим не нравится, когда из-за минорных правок всплывают старые вопросы на главной.

В вашем примере исправление **Вод** на **Ввод** никак не влияет в целом на качество вопроса. Правки изначально призваны для существенного улучшения качества вопросов.

При достижении 2000 репутации, вы [сможете править вопросы/ответы вне очереди](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

Comment: В корне не согласен! Я не хочу видеть подобные ошибки и считаю что их нужно исправлять.

Comment: @Other их вне очереди могут исправлять проверенные пользователи. Нет смысла ими очередь забивать.

Comment: Я смотрю, что вы только что сделали это исправление в один символ самостоятельно. То есть, на самом деле, это ограничение действует не для всех. Для кого оно не действует и смогу ли я избавиться от него по достижению определённого уровня репутации?

Comment: @РостиславКрасный https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit 2000 репутации надо.

Comment: Проверенные участники могут и не увидеть, а могут и вообще забить. Хотя уже есть кто-то, кто обратил внимание и хочет исправить. Вряд ли в проверке придётся долго голову ломать - апрувать такое или нет.

Comment: @Suvitruf да, я прочитал ваш ответ после редактирования. Теперь понятно.

Comment: @Other в очереди такие правки отклонят как "несущественные".

Comment: Ага, тогда и ошибки вроде "чо" тоже считать "несущественными"? И вообще - когда это грамматическая ценность стала в символах измерятся?

Comment: @Other ценность вопроса в передаче информации. Грамотность - приятное дополнение. От того, что там "чо" вместо "что", не делает вопрос менее понятным.

Comment: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Ic_dy_8Zx6E/hqdefault.jpg

Comment: @Suvitruf Нашёл полезную таблицу с описанием получаемых привилегий при достижении определённых уровней репутации: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: @РостиславКрасный ну да, я ссылку оттуда и взял)

Comment: @РостиславКрасный если правка опечатки действительно сушественная, то поправте и дополните чем нибудь до 6 символов. Проверяюший обычно может улучшить правку и удалить лишние символы, если конечно он найдёт, что опечатка действительно очень грубая. Правка "ее" на "её" будет отклонена.  Положительный пример, [тут поправлен только один символ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/288619) .

Comment: @РостиславКрасный или в комментариях автору написать, чтоб сам поправил.