# Необходимость 6-символьной правки

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, очередь-проверок, правки

Вот к примеру есть вопрос, вопрос нормальный и претензии только к оформлению, в 
основном есть проблема новичков.

И всё можно исправить, только выделив код, либо добавив цитату или ссылку.
И читаемость улучшит и визуально лучше выглядит.

Есть ли смысл в минимальной 6-символьной правке?

Или это способ разгрузить очередь проверок? 
Я за то чтоб ее убрать.

Comment: Да, это для очереди проверок. Когда достаточно репутации, можно хоть односимвольные правки делать. Тут уже есть такие вопросы, кстати.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что делать, если для правки требуется лишь отформатировать код?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5904) и [ещё](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/508/176217)